# Many to Many relationship creation for existing object in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

Two classes:

```
class Investor
  field :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
 field :name
 has_and_belongs_to_many :investors
end
```

I already have users and investors I don't want to create new. What is the way of inclusing like

```
@user=User.first
@investor=Investor.first
@inves_sec=Investor.last
```

Now what is the way to add @investor and @invest_sec to the user investors id, all the command I found in mongoid doc create new investor object, I wasn't able to find thorugh which you can use existing object.

Comment: I don't follow your question. `investor.users.push(@investor)`?

Comment: Thanks it works, I was doing @investor.id that's why it was an issue, thanks for your comment. You can post this as answer @user.investors.push(@investor) then next one. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough as you could do something like:

```
@first_investor = Investor.first
@user.investors.push(@first_investor)
```

There are a lots of examples [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_and_belongs_to_many) of various scenarios dealing with relationships/references.